# Getting rid of type 3 fonts for manuscript

Tags: fonts, eps

I am trying to submit a pdf file made with pdflatex on linux to a journal. I did not realize the issues with type 3 fonts. Using pdffonts, the issue seems to be coming from .eps image files that I have from using \includegraphics.

Unfortunately, I made the graphics using python and matplotlib and from doing research it seems like by default it will make texts using type 3 fonts. Worst of all, all the data to make these graphs are on my school computer and I am on break for a month. I have spent the last couple of hours trying to research anyway to get around remaking these figures. Is there anyway I can convert a .eps file to not have type 3 fonts once it is created? I've tried searching for solutions during the compiling process with pdflatex or using inkscape or something to convert it, all to no avail.

I'm really hoping somebody has a solution so I don't have to wait a month to get this paper submitted.

Comment: it depends how much text is in the eps,you could perhaps use psfrag to redo it with tex fonts does python really use type3 fonts? where does it find them from? usual source of type3 is old installations of tex.

Comment: Note that unless your discipline is very unusual or its staff are located in a country which will not be feasting for the next couple of weeks, your paper will probably only sit there fore the best part of the next 3 weeks or so anyway.